# Plugin email sender incorrectly uses ISO-8859-1

Tags: email, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using a free plugin:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-inquiry-1.html

That works great, with the exception of sendind its emails with the wrong encoding (ISO-8859-1), thus rendering garbled text (since the input text is UTF-8)

```
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q? (...) = <address@example.com>
```

Every other email send by the platform is correctly encoded in UTF-8.

The code sending the email seems rather usual:

```
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                ->setToName($userName)
                ->setToEmail($userEmail)
                ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                ->setSubject('Questão '.$productName)
                ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
                ->setFromName($storeName)
                ->setType('html');
```

I've tried htmlentities(), but the result is no better.
How do I force this to use UTF-8?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it's not your SMTP configuration that's messued up? or maybe there are options in the admin to switch encoding?

Comment: How would I now that my smtp configuration is messed up? All other 'regular' emails sents by magento (new account,etc), show up fine. There are no encoding options on the admin... thanks

Comment: I see, then is this module using a .html template file for emails or transactional email tempalte from the admin?
In case it's using a .html file, check that this file is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Add thought of that also: ```file -bi user_inquiry.html``` returns text/html; charset=utf-8. Indeed, if I remove the body and just add an accented char to the setFromName, the problem still manifests itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this may be a duplicate, but I did not quite understand the answer given on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308454/magento-issue-with-email-charset

The problem, you see, is that `Zend_Mail` [defaults to ISO-8859-1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.mail.character-sets.html), unless it is instantiated with a different encoding.

A search on the Magento 1.9.0.1 code base on `new Zend_Mail` returns:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Template.php:263:  $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:141:  $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email.php:103:  $mail = new Zend_Mail();
```

Yes, that's right, the last one is *not* configured to use utf-8.

Personally, I consider this a bug in Magento, and have directly patched the offending file.

Comment: it's weird, I never had any encoding issue with my Magento, not having overriden the mails though. Glad you found an answer to your own question, please accept it.